# Print an array forwarded from a servlet to a JSP

Tags: arrays, jsp, servlets, printing, jstl

I have forwarded an array userName[][] from a servlet to a JSP. I can access the array elements like `${userName[2][3]}`, but i cant iterate through the array using a variable. e.g. `${userName[i][j]}` or `${userName[<%=i>][<%=j>]}` dont work.

also, should i declare my index variables as var(JS) as my code also uses JS to plot a graph from the array,or do I need to use JSTL? I'm a complete newbie to JSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you iterate through an array in JSTL (Note that I pluralized your userName variable, since it's an array):

```
<c:forEach var="userName" items="userNames">
    // do something with the userName
</c:forEach>
```

Since you array is an array of arrays, you can nest two iterations:

```
<c:forEach var="innerArray" items="userNames">
    <c:forEach var="element" items="innerArray">
         // do something with the element
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Note that JavaScript executes at client-side, whereas the JSP is executed at server-side. When JS code executes, it doesn't have access to your server-side Java array. If you need to access the contents of the Java array at client-side, you should serialize it with JSON, and parse the resulting JSON String in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you Nizet,but I would like to use the indexed notation,so that I can access any part of the array,instead of going through them one by one sequentially. can someone help me with that?

Comment: `<c:set var="i" value="5"/><c:set var="j" value="7"/>${userName[i][j]}` should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Just one more thing, shouldn't we write it as ${userName[${i}][${j}]} ?

Comment: No. Once you are between `${` and `}`, you define an EL expression, and such an EL expression may use several attributes.

Comment: Thanks,that solved it. will the same approach work for a list as well?

Comment: Yes. A list and an array are treated the same way in EL expressions.